# Read List in List

Tags: python

I have a text file and there is 3 lines on data in it.

```
[1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3]
[1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3]
```

I try to open and get data in it.

```
with open("rafine.txt") as f:
    l = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
    f.close()
```

now i have list in list.
if i say `print(l[0])` it shows me `[1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3]`
But i want to get numbers in it.
So when i write `print(l[0][0])`
i want to see `1` but it show me `[`

how can i fix this ?

Comment: No, you have a list of strings. You haven't parsed the input into lists yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach depends on what assumption you make about the data in your text file:

### ast.literal_eval

If the data in your file is formatted the same way, it would be inside python source-code, the best approach is to use literal_eval:

```
from ast import literal_eval

data = [] # will contain list of lists
with open("filename") as f:
    for line in f:
        row = literal_eval(line)
        data.append(row)
```

or, the short version:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    data = [literal_eval(line) for line in f]
```

### re.findall

If you can make few assumptions about the data, using regular expressions to find all digits might be a way forward. The below builds lists by simply extracting any digits in the text file, regardless of separators or other characters in the file:

```
import re

data = [] # will contain list of lists
with open("filename") as f:
    for line in f:
        row = [int(i) for i in re.findall(r'\d+', line)]
        data.append(row)
```

or, in short:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    data= [ [int(i) for i in re.findall(r'\d+', line)] for line in f ]
```

### handwritten parsing

If both options are not suitable, there is always an option to parse by hand, to tailor for the exact format:

```
data = [] # will contain list of lists
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        row = [int(i) for i in line[1:-1].split(, )]
        data.append(row)
```

The `[1,-1]` will remove the first and last character (the brackets), then `split(", ")` will split it into a list. `for i in ...` will iterate over the items in this list (assigning i to each item) and `int(i)` will convert i to an integer.

Comment: that's not a good idea, usually you either use literal_eval or json

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to parse the lines from the file & build the matrix:

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open("test.txt") as f:
    matrix = []
    for line in f:
        row = literal_eval(line)
        matrix.append(row)

print(matrix[0][0])
print(matrix[1][4])
print(matrix[2][8])
```

result:

```
1
3
1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import json

with open("rafine.txt") as f:
   for line in f.readlines():
      line = json.loads(line)
      print(line)
```